# How did $(x)^6 x^9$ become $x^{24} x^9$ in this textbook example?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There an example problem that I’m a little confused about. The problem is has cube square root with $(x)^6 x^9$ which is equal to cube square root of $x^{24} x^9$.

I’m confused on how they got they $x^{24}$ from.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a typo, they intended an index of 4 inside the brackets in the leftmost expression

Comment: Oh thank you so basically it should be 4 not 3?

Comment: I agree with the typo theory. There's no reason to have surrounded that first $x$ in parentheses unless an explicit grouping was needed, as in writing "$(x^4)^6$" (which then becomes $x^{4\cdot 6}$, which is $x^{24}$). ... BTW, the term isn't "cube square root"; it's just "cube root". :)

Comment: As @bounceback said, it appears that $(x^4)^6 \cdot x^9$ was intended under the cube root symbol. Everything else is consistent with this change.