# Converting a radical to a fractional exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, radicals

I want to understand how to convert a radical to a fractional exponent. Given the following equation:

$\sqrt[3]{(x)^6\cdot x^9}=\sqrt[3]{x^{24}\cdot x^9}=\sqrt[3]{x^{33}}=x^{\frac{33}3}=x^{11}$

How does: $\sqrt[3]{(x)^6\cdot x^9} = \sqrt[3]{x^{24}\cdot x^9}\;\;$??

Comment: $(x^4)^6 = \underbrace{x^4 x^4 \cdots x^4}_6 = \underbrace{(xxxx)(xxxx) \cdots (xxxx)}_6 = \underbrace{xxxxxxxx \cdots xxxx}_{24} = x^{24}$.

Comment: My original equation was changed from $\sqrt[3]{(x)^6 * x^9}$ to $\sqrt[3]{(x^4)^6 * x^9}$ . Why was the original equation modified. Are these expressions equal?

Comment: There's a typo in your textbook. See the question ["How did $(x)^6x^9$ become $x^{24}x^9$ in this textbook example?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4053962/409).

Comment: "Why was the original equation modified. Are these expressions equal? "  They are *not*.  That is the problem.  $\sqrt[3]{(x)^6 \cdot x^9} \ne \sqrt[3]{x^{24}\cdot x^9}$.  The textbook you have had a typo and the question you asked is simply wrong.  ... I assume the textbooks typo was the problem $\sqrt[3]{(x^{\color{red}4})^6\cdot 9}$ which *will* equal $\sqrt[3]{x^{24}\cdot x^9}$ for the standard rules of exponents.  The person who edited fixed the typo figuring that that *wasn't* what was causing you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power rules of exponent :

1. $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$ $\to \sqrt[3]{(x^4)^6\cdot x^9} = \sqrt[3]{x^{24}\cdot x^9}$
2. $a^ma^n=a^{m+n}$ $\to \sqrt[3]{x^{24}\cdot x^9}$$=\sqrt[3]{x^{33}}$
3. $\sqrt[n]{a}=a^{\frac{1}{n}},\sqrt[n]{a^m}=a^{\frac{m}{n}}  \to  \sqrt[3]{x^{33}}$$=x^{\frac{33}{3}}=x^{11}\;$

Or,

$\sqrt[3]{(x^4)^6\cdot x^9} = \sqrt[3]{x^{24}\cdot x^9}$(2)$=\sqrt[3]{x^{33}}$$=x^{\frac{33}{3}}=x^{11}\;$

Comment: My original equation was changed from $\sqrt[3]{(x)^6 * x^9}$ to $\sqrt[3]{(x^4)^6 * x^9}$ . Why was the original equation modified. Are these expressions equal? Your answer makes sense to me in the event that the expression is: $\sqrt[3]{(x^4)^6 * x^9}$ . However it does not make sense to me that: $\sqrt[3]{(x)^6 * x^9}$ is equal...

Comment: Don’t know who changed your original question. The two expressions are equal only when x=0, -1,+1 (given x is real).

Comment: Thats what i thought. I modified my original question back to reflect what it was initially: $\sqrt[3]{(x)^6 * x^9}$ .

Comment: It's possible that the textbook may contain a typo if in fact: $\sqrt[3]{(x)^6\cdot x^9}$  doesn't equal $\sqrt[3]{x^{24}\cdot x^9}\;\;$

Comment: Most likely, what matters is you caught its mistake:-).

Answer (score 0):

The expressions you wrote are not equal for more or less the reasons you have identified, that $x^6 \neq x^{24}$.